# How to get data from the following form?

Tags: jquery, django, forms

What's the right way to get data from the following form? I would like to get it into a Django view or just JQuery and make ajax call to Django.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/css-toggle-switch@latest/dist/toggle-switch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<fieldset>
  <legend>View</legend>
  <div class="switch-toggle alert alert-light">
    <input id="week" name="view" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="week" onclick="">Week</label>

    <input id="month" name="view" type="radio">
    <label for="month" onclick="">Month</label>

    <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a `<form>` tag and specify the method and action.

```
<form method="GET" action="/home/form/">
<fieldset>
  <legend>View</legend>
  <div class="switch-toggle alert alert-light">
    <input id="week" name="view" value="week" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="week" onclick="">Week</label>

    <input id="month" name="view" value="month" type="radio">
    <label for="month" onclick="">Month</label>

    <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<form>
```

Now in your views.py, you can get the data like this:

```
def form_data(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        week = request.GET.get('view') # name of the input
        # do something with it
```

That's one way to get the form data from a view.

Comment: Thanks for reply, @Rone. I did exactly like that in the beginning. But I got a value 'on' but I can't figure out which one was selected.

Comment: Can you please post the error you got and your view code?

Comment: There's no error. My code is exactly the same as yours. I just get a value 'on'. If I switch to GET method, I also see all names of radio buttons equal to 'on' value. I guess that request.GET.get('view') doesn't really return True/False value.

Comment: The input tags were missing the `value` attributes. I've updated the code and now it gives me the value of the radio button selected. Try that and see if it works for you, too.

Comment: worked perfectly! Thanks :)
That was quite stupid of me not to figure it out. You saved me!

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help